# checkbox value edit and update using explode php

Tags: php, html, checkbox

How to fix the problem Notice:

> Undefined variable: b in
>   C:\wamp64\www\MyFolder\version1.1\fms\build\english\equipment.php on
>   line 904
>
> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in
>   C:\wamp64\www\MyFolder\version1.1\fms\build\english\equipment.php on
>   line 904

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 35px;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="equipment[]" value="Tv" class="custom-control-input" 
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["equipment_id"]))
    {
    $id = $_POST['equipment_id'];
    $query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE id='$id'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $a = $row["equipment"];
    $b = explode(",", $a);
    print_r($b);
    }

if (in_array("Tv", $b))
    {
    echo "checked";
    }

?> >
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <img src="img/equipments/tv-icon.png" width="25px" height="25px">
        <span class="custom-control-description">TVs</span>
    </label>
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 35px;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="equipment[]" value="Phone" class="custom-control-input">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <img src="img/equipments/phone-icon.png" width="25px" height="25px">
        <span class="custom-control-description">Phone</span>
    </label>
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 35px;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="equipment[]" value="Fan" class="custom-control-input">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <img src="img/equipments/fan-icon.png" width="25px" height="25px">
        <span class="custom-control-description">Fan</span>
    </label>
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="margin-right: 35px;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="equipment[]" value="Mirror" class="custom-control-input">
        <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        <img src="img/equipments/mirror-icon.png" width="25px" height="25px">
        <span class="custom-control-description">Mirrors</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Put the `in_array()` in the `isset()` condition

Comment: What value you are getting for $row["equipment"] ?

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, place the `in_array()` condition in the `isset()` condition. The reason for the undefined variable is that `$b` only exists in the `isset()` condition. So when you leave the `isset()` condition and try to access `$b`, it throws the errors

```
if (isset()){
#your isset() code

    if(in_array()){
#in_array() code

    } #place in_array() inside isset()
} # end isset()
```

As a tip,  always make a habit of defining your variables before use..  And lastly please use prepared statements for your queries..

Answer (score 1):

Top  of the php code please declare  the array $b

```
 $b=array();
```

in your code you write a if condition and if it not satisfied then $b variable is undefined. So before the condition please declare the array like.

```
$b=array();
if (isset($_POST["equipment_id"])) {
//your code        
}
```

Thank you

Comment: While this removes the undefined error,  the `in_array()` would just be an empty array..

Comment: I think in your post  $_POST["equipment_id"] have no value please check the name used in your form.